# Let $z_k = \sin(2\pi k/7)+j \sin (2\pi k/7)$ Find $\sum_{k=1}^{6} 1/(1+z_k)^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $z_k=\sin(2\pi k/7)+j \sin(2\pi k/7)$
Find $\sum_{k=1}^{6}1/(1+z_k)^2$

Comment: What does mean $j$?

Comment: It is imaginary part

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the real question is to compute :

$$\sum_{k=0}^6\frac1{(1+e^{2ik\pi/7})^2}$$

Here is a slightly general point of view...

Consider an *odd* natural integer $n$ et $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2i\pi}n\right)$. Let us compute :

$$\boxed{S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{(1+\omega^k)^2}}$$

Since $n$ is supposed to be odd, the condition $1+\omega^k\neq0$ holds for all integer $k$.

Here is now the main tool : if $P$ is a separable polynomial, that is of the form $P=a\prod\limits_{k=1}^n(X-\alpha_k)$ where $a\neq0$ and $\alpha_k\ne\alpha_\ell$ for every $k\ne\ell$, then :

$$\frac{P'}P=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{X-\alpha_k}$$

Applying this to $P=X^n-1$, and using $P=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(X-\omega^k)$, we get :

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{X-\omega^k}=\frac{nX^{n-1}}{X^n-1}$$

Differentiating both sides and changing the sign, we obtain :

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{(X-\omega^k)^2}=\frac{nX^{2n-2}+n(n-1)X^{n-2}}{(X^n-1)^2}$$
Evaluating at $-1$ (and reminding that $n$ is odd) :

> $$\boxed{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{(1+\omega^k)^2}=\frac14\left(n+(-1)^nn(n-1)\right)}$$

As a special case (taking $n=7$) :

$$\sum_{k=0}^6\frac1{(1+e^{2ik\pi/7})^2}=-\frac{35}4$$

Comment: Classical and nicely done.